# Change position of leaflet label

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I'd like to add labels to my leaflet-markers, and then position them above and horizontally centered for the marker icon.

With the labelAnchor option in the Leaflet.label plugin I can manually adjust every label so that I get what I want, and for now I've added a fixed width to my labels so that I know the text will be centered. But there must be a better way to achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/NYGvibeke/frUf4/3/

```
<style type="text/css">

  .labeltext { width: 120px; text-align: center; border:none; }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var myIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-       style/512/Maps-and-Geolocation-Marker-icon.png',
        iconSize:     [18, 30], 
        iconAnchor:   [10, 30], 
        labelAnchor: [-80, -40]
    });

    var layer = new L.StamenTileLayer("toner-lite", {maxZoom: 10});
    var map = new L.Map("map", {
        center: new L.LatLng(30, 100),
        zoom: 4,
        maxZoom: 12,
        minZoom: 2
    });

    map.addLayer(layer);

    var marker1 = L.marker([25, 100], {icon: myIcon}).bindLabel('This is a label text', { noHide: true, className: 'labeltext'}).addTo(map);

</script>
```

Comment: By default it's not a supported behavior on the plugin you're using. In your case, your might be interested in retrieving the width of the label element (based on the HTML element or based on the text length) and dynamically set the label anchor. It's not as good as it should be but it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
.labeltext { width: 120px}
```

to

```
.labeltext { width: auto}
```

The `auto` value will dynamically size the width of the label.

**UPDATE**

Actually, that's only part of it. Here's the rest in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uytLD/).  Basically, you need to dynamically assign the position based on the number of characters.  It takes a little bit of calibration (depending on font typeface/size), but here's what I came up with for `labelAnchor`:

```
[-label[0].length*2.5-20, -40]
```

Comment: Thanks, lando and @nicolas-boonaert, I created a new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYGvibeke/f7dUM/1/) where I did what you suggested.

Comment: Glad to see you got it working! I thought the fiddle I provided had an example for you, but it must not have updated... sorry about that!